# PHP Curl parsing and form posting (little tricky)

Tags: php, parsing, curl, web-crawler

I have a problem with parsing specific URL. Target page is created in ASP and i have problems with CURL crawling through pages. There are 10 records per page but can be changed to 100 with select box on that page. There is also pagination bellow results but not ordinary one where URL is changed but some kind of javascript with post back.

Do you have any ideas about how to crawl through pages (pagination) or how to at least set page size to 100 insted of 10 (default) and submit a form with Curl.

You can see a target page at this URL:

[ess.gov.si/iskalci_zaposlitve/prosta_delovna_mesta/seznam?q=1&s=1](http://www.ess.gov.si/iskalci_zaposlitve/prosta_delovna_mesta/seznam?q=1&s=1)

It's a local site but i guess you will see what i mean. Select box for number of results per page is at the top right (Št. izpisov na strani) Pagination is bellow results.

So any ideas about how to parse this. It's not really a problem for parsing first 10 results but i want to crawl through page or at least set a number of result on 100 instead of 10.

Comment: URL doesn't work, and you should really paste your code of what have you tried...

Comment: Copy and paste URL and maybe add a www. in front. I tried without www and it's works for me (redirect to www) I know there is no link in question but i didn't want to add it.

Comment: Below the pagination are links to full Excel / RTF / ... exports. Why don't you use these?

Comment: Yeah saw that. The problem is that i need to parse a link where i need to parse additional details from it. Excel file doesn't contain links.